# vscodeの自動整形による文字化け

Tags: r, vscode

vscodeを使用してRのプログラミングを行っているのですが，vscodeの機能である自動整形(Format On Save)をONにしたところ文字化けしてしまいました．

```
print(paste("標本平均 : ", mean(y), seq = ""))
```

これを保存すると

```
print(paste("<e6><a8><99><e6><9c><ac><e5><b9><b3><e5><9d><87> : ", mean(y), seq = ""))
```

このように文字化けが発生してしまいます．

対処法を教えていただけないでしょうか．

#### 追記

拡張機能はこちら https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r を使用しております。自動整形後のファイルの文字コードを確認したところ、us-asciiとなっておりました。

Comment: R用の拡張機能として何をお使いですか？　また、このファイルの文字コードはUTF-8でしょうか？

Comment: 拡張機能はこちら https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r を使用しております。自動整形後のファイルの文字コードを確認したところ、us-asciiとなっておりました。

Comment: 今私の手元ですぐに試せないのでコメントにて済ませますが、文字コードがUTF-8でないのが怪しそうです。

Comment: Format on saveによってutf-8のファイルがus-asciiに変更されたことが確認できました．拡張子が.Rでないもの(.pyや.cなど)ではFormat on saveによって文字コードの変更は行われませんでした．